# ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0)

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día.

Tengo una problema en mi aplicación que tengo desarrollada en laravel.
Al entrar al login del administrador me manda error: **ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0)** en la carpeta public_html/shop/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php

```
public static function closeOutputBuffers(int $targetLevel, bool $flush): void
    {
        $status = ob_get_status(true);
        $level = \count($status);
        $flags = PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE | ($flush ? PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE : PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);

        while ($level-- > $targetLevel && ($s = $status[$level]) && (!isset($s['del']) ? !isset($s['flags']) || ($s['flags'] & $flags) === $flags : $s['del'])) {
            if ($flush) {
                ob_end_flush();
            } else {
                ob_end_clean();
            }
        }
    }
```

No encuentro una solución. Les agradecería si me comentaran como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta relacionado a que tienes Zlib activado en el php.ini o en algún otro lado, puedes desactivarlo:

```
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38694583/4717133

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.

Comment: si, mi respuesta soluciona tu pregunta te recomiendo, marcarla como resuelta. saludos

Comment: No me deja hasta en 5 min.

Comment: ok esperemos entonces y saludos.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.